# can we write javascript code in jsp which is of with struts html tag library

Tags: html-select

this is phani kumar,

Actually, i am writing one page to show product details. In that i written code to display the 
productid list in jsp page with the help of  and  tags
. but the main problem is, based on the selection of productid, i trying to show the product details(productname, productcost, productstock..like).But i am facing problems to work this.

I am trying it with javascript, but because of struts html taglibrary, i am getting problems here, could u please give me solutions to resolve this problem anyone.

and can anybody tell how to get dropdown selection value into javascript(if we are using  tag library in struts)

Answer (score 0):

How are you using javascript to create your view? You should be able to use

```
<logic:iterate>
```

to traverse your product collection, then

```
    <bean:write .../>
```

to display information from each product.

```
<html:select>
```

will create a dropdown in your form. Use

```
 <html:option>, <html:options>, or <html:optionsCollection>
```

to populate each item in the dropdown.